# How to send only one UDP packet with netcat?

Tags: udp, netcat

I want to send only one short value in a UDP packet, but running the command

```
echo -n "hello" | nc -4u localhost 8000
```

I can see that the server is getting the *hello* stuff but I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to quit the netcat command.

How can I make it quit after sending *hello*?

---

Sorry, for the noise, I re-read the man page and found the `-q` option.

```
 echo -n "hello" | nc -4u -q1 localhost 8000
```

works (it quits after 1 second).

For some reason it does not work with `-q0`.

Comment: Man page on debian: `-q seconds:  after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit. If seconds is negative, wait forever.`

Answer (score 255):

If you are using bash, you might as well write

```
echo -n "hello" >/dev/udp/localhost/8000
```

and avoid all the idiosyncrasies and incompatibilities of netcat.

This also works sending to other hosts, ex:

```
echo -n "hello" >/dev/udp/remotehost/8000
```

These are not "real" devices on the file system, but bash "special" [aliases](https://web.archive.org/web/20161018130608/http://nerotux.tuxfamily.org/articles.php?article_id=72). There is additional information in [the Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).

Comment: Ok, you are right, let me just make it explicit that this won't work with ZSH.

Comment: How does one get this packet?

Comment: This is way better than mucking with netcat. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: So much fast.simpler/more reliable/better than netcat for a udp packet. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for answer, @JúlioTurollaRibeiro, no need to be explicit in comment, answer is explicit enough : "If you are using bash ..."

Comment: For some reason, I needed to use `127.0.0.1` instead on `localhost` on Ubuntu 14.04. (Yes, I do have `localhost` in `/etc/hosts`.)

Comment: @tuomassalo Good tip. This also applies for OS X 10.11. While also running bash, as zsh doesn't have the /dev/udp

Comment: On OS X 10.10 there's no /dev/udp but simple echo "message" > /dev/udp/127.0.0.1/5000 (for example) works like a charm

Comment: `/dev/udp/` is not a real file. It's only a file name interpreted specially by bash.

Comment: maybe a mention that echo -n is writing without a newline char

Comment: @PeterEisentraut So that's why it doesn't show up with ls -la /dev/udp  ...?

Comment: @JohnyTex Yes, because it only exists in bash, not in ls.

Comment: So what if we actually have something at /dev/udp. How do we access that? @PeterEisentraut

Comment: `localhost` doesn't work but `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` works. Great hint, thx!

Comment: I tried this to talk to another machine on my LAN like `echo -n "hello" >/dev/udp/10.1.1.10/4000` and it doesn't work

Comment: This is pure gold! I am going to use it for the rest of my life. Thank you so much for sharing.

Answer (score 51):

I did not find the `-q1` option on my netcat. Instead I used the `-w1` option. Below is the bash script I did to send an udp packet to any host and port:

```
#!/bin/bash

def_host=localhost
def_port=43211

HOST=${2:-$def_host}
PORT=${3:-$def_port}

echo -n "$1" | nc -4u -w1 $HOST $PORT
```

Comment: OS X works this: "echo -n "test" | nc -4u -w0 localhost 9999" as SimonW says

Answer (score 17):

On a current netcat (v0.7.1) you have a -c switch:

```
-c, --close                close connection on EOF from stdin
```

Hence,

```
echo "hi" | nc -cu localhost 8000
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Important to note that this is true only for GNU netcat, but not for BSD netcat.

Comment: For clarity, with Linux-based netcat, the -c option requires a command as an argument, which "executes the given argument via /bin/bash" - https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/nc.1.html

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem but I use `-w 0` option to send only one packet and quit.
You should use this command :

```
echo -n "hello" | nc -4u -w0 localhost 8000
```

Comment: nc 1.10-41+b1 does not accept `-w0`. Error: invalid wait-time 0

Comment: @palik that looks like a nc.traditional version string. -q0 should work for you.

Answer (score 6):

Netcat sends one packet per newline. So you're fine. If you do anything more complex then you might need something else.

I was fooling around with Wireshark when I realized this. Don't know if it helps.

Comment: I think this is only correct for TCP. With UDP, it will send multiple lines in one packet (if they fit).

Comment: No. Simply test `echo -n "hello\nworld" >/dev/udp/localhost/514` and you'll get 2 lines

Comment: @bebbo, 2 lines, one packet

Comment: @bebbo is right. This answer wasn't even correct for UDP specifically as it does this in TCP

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately nc is not a unique name for a single tool. To find out which nc you have, look at the first line of output from `nc -h`. To send a single UDP packet and exit immediately, use the appropriate arguments for your specific nc.

- GNU `nc -uc localhost 8000 <<<hello`
- BSD `nc -uq0 localhost 8000 <<<hello`
- traditional `nc -uq0 localhost 8000 <<<hello`
- BusyBox nc does not support UDP
- Others? Please leave a comment!

Related but thankfully not calling themselves `nc`:

- nmap: `ncat -u --send-only localhost 8000 <<<hello`
- bash: `echo hello >/dev/udp/localhost/8000`
- `socat - UDP:localhost:8000 <<<hello`
- `sendip -p ipv4 -p udp -ud 8000 -d $'hello\n' localhost`
- `packetsender -ua localhost 8000 $'hello\n'`
- There are so many more! But the original question was about netcat...

If you want a portable nc wrapper for sending a single UDP packet, try this as `nc-udp-oneshot.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

helpword=$(nc -h 2>&1 | awk '{print$1;exit}')

case $helpword in
  *GNU*) args=-uc ;;
  *) args=-uq0 ;;
esac
exec nc $args "$@"
```

Now you can run `echo -n hello | ./nc-udp-oneshot.sh` with whichever nc happens to be installed. Or `xxd -r -p <<<68656c6c6f | ./nc-udp-oneshot.sh` for sending more complicated binary data, represented in hex.