# send udp packet with netcat without waiting for answer

Tags: macos, udp, timeout, netcat

Hi i need to send udp packet with netcat without waiting for answer i tried with -w0 but something it bug and don't work

if you need this is my command :

> echo 413055 | perl -ne 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/print chr hex $1/gie' | nc -4u -w0  192.168.111.247 8899

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Answer (score 2):

the wait option is -q (seconds):

```
echo 'test' | netcat -q 1 -u 192.168.111.247 8899
```

As is it wait a second and then quit. But it does not work with -q 0.

You could also try something like :

```
echo 'test' > /dev/udp/192.168.111.247/8899
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments needed to exit immediately depend on which nc you have.

For GNU nc:

`xxd -r -p <<<413055 | nc -uc 192.168.111.247 8899`

For BSD or traditional nc, -q 0 does work:

`xxd -r -p <<<413055 | nc -uq0 192.168.111.247 8899`

See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75431334/7308581) with more detail.